# Javascript Conflict (Fade-In VS. jQuery Accordion)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using a basic fade-in javascript function for a title image on one of my pages and when I try to use the jQuery vertical accordion menus on that page, it prevents the title from being loaded. I've gone through all the javascript code (of the files that are used for the accordions) and I've figured out the function that conflicts. The following function is my basic fade in script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('html').addClass('js_on');

    $(window).load(function (){
        $('#slideshow').fadeIn(2000);
    });
</script>
```

Here is the couple lines of code that conflicts (the 'if' statement doesn't conflict. It's everything before it but I included the 'if' statement just so you have the full function):

```
function $(element) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0, elements = [], length = arguments.length; i < length; i++)
  elements.push($(arguments[i]));
   return elements;
  }
  if (typeof element == 'string')
    element = document.getElementById(element);
  return Element.extend(element);
}
```

I'm wracking my brain on this one. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: What is `function $(element) {` supposed to be? doesn't look valid.

Comment: It's basically part of this huge JS file that control part of the vertical nested accordion menus. When I take it out, the title fades in but the accordion stops working and through the thousands of lines of code, I've narrowed it down to those lines exactly.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `function $(element) {` creates a function named `$`, thus overriding jquery in the scope it is defined in.

Comment: Looks like this script is simply conflicting with jquery because of it's name. try using http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noConflict/

Comment: I would use that in the first block of code, correct?

Comment: Are you trying to define a function named `$`?  If so, why?  If not, are you trying invoke a function on `document.ready`?  If so, it should be `$(function() { ... })`.  If not, what the heck are you trying to do?

Comment: And BTW, I think you are "racking" your brain (i.e., torturing it as if on a [rack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_%28torture%29)) not "wracking" it (i.e., wrecking it and using an obsolete spelling of ["wreck"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wrack)).

Comment: The function $(element) is part of the larger JS file that I'm trying to figure out for the vertical accordion. When I structure the function 'correctly' it doesn't work. That's what I'm trying to figure out. I've uploaded the full file to my server (http://www.miller-media.com/js/prototype.js). It's line 1251 (I've also labeled it '/*PROBLEM*/').

Comment: I'm curious; which solution did you end up going with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides two methods of accessing it: `jQuery()` and the `$()` shorthand. They are equivalent.

Your accordion code is overwriting the `$()` function, which leaves you with just `jQuery()`.

So one option you have is to simply use the longer syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('html').addClass('js_on');

jQuery(window).load(function (){
    jQuery('#slideshow').fadeIn(2000);
});
</script>
```

Another option is to pass `jQuery` into a closure and then use the shorthand `$` syntax inside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Self-executing function that calls itself immediately
(function($){    
  // Inside this function, '$' now refers to the argument that was passed in, which is jQuery
  $('html').addClass('js_on');

  $(window).load(function (){
      $('#slideshow').fadeIn(2000);
  });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

And another option is to use the accordion from the jQuery UI library ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ ), which will let you avoid the whole conflicting issue in the first place.